# In RStudio, where is knitr markdown output located?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

In RStudio, I set the knit option to current folder :
[image: see knitr option]

When I knit a Markdown document to HTML, this surprisingly happens in a temporary directory (for example : 'Temp\RtmpOa3xSM\preview-11e8c6644fdd.dir' directory).

As far as I can remember, this didn't happen previously : the knit would happen in the directory I selected in the options.

Option [rstudio.markdownToHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174565/r-in-rstudio-how-do-i-make-knitr-output-to-a-different-folder-to-avoid-clutteri) isn't set :

```
getOption('rstudio.markdownToHTML')
NULL
```

When I close the HTML preview, the HTML document disappears.

The only solution I found to keep the HTML document is to open the document in a Browser and to save it from there.

Bug or am I missing something?
Thanks for your help!

[EDIT] other Win 10 users reported to me the same problem

Comment: Interesting - I cannot reproduce this. Just updated to RStudio 1.3.959 and R4.0.1 (on Win10): The "Knit Directory" is respected and the HTML file is created next to the RMD file. The HTML file is not deleted when I close the preview. Is there something weird about the name of your RMD file or the directory where it is located?

Comment: @CL, thanks for your feedback. Important to know it's not a generalized bug. Nothing particular about the file name, happens unfortunately with any .Rmd

Comment: Can you add some details - what exactly is happening? I guess: 1) You create (save) a minimal RMD file `yourfile.Rmd`. 2) You hit the knit button. 3) The preview opens and displays your HTML file. At this point, your file explorer displays `yourfile.html` next to `yourfile.Rmd`. (Or does it only exist in the temporary directory?) 4) You close the preview and the HTML file vanishes. \\ Is that correct? What does the RMarkdown log say?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58955908/2706569 And maybe even this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48774057/2706569 Are you in an RStudio Project?

Comment: @CL, thanks for your feedback! I think your second link explains exactly what happens when I do what you described in your previous comment. I was in the **vignette folder of a package**... To avoid cluttering RStudio deletes the HTML here, didn't know about this! Can you please write down the answer so that I can close the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under certain conditions, RStudio moves the knitted (HTML or PDF) file to a temporary directory (located under `tempdir()`). These conditions are:

- You are in a RStudio Project.
- The "Project build tools" are set to "Package".
- The RMD file is located in a subdirectory `vignettes`.
- Knitting is initiated with the "Knit" button in RStudio.

Typically, this happens when knitting a package vignette and has the purpose of ["keep[ing] your vignettes folder from becoming cluttered with HTML files"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777215/2706569).

Changing the Project build tools, changing the folder name or closing the project prevents this behavior. Another way to keep the generated (HTML or PDF) file is to call `rmarkdown::render` interactively (although this is [not exactly equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34591487/2706569) to the "Knit" button).

Note that this only affects where the generated file will be saved. The Working Directory while knitting is unaffected.

Comment: Where can I find the tempdir() folder?

Comment: @Jantje Just type tempdir() into the console; this prints the path.